# Fixed position is css overridden by absolute position. Can I get alternate solution for this?

Tags: html, css

I want a header throughout the page when I scroll so I use a header position as fixed.

```
.header-title{
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
}
```

I have used an image on my page with some text on it:

[image: image example]

So I used position absolute.

```
.bottom-left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 19px;
}
```

When I scroll up the fixed position is overridden by absolute:

Actual page:

[image: actual page]

Doubt image:

[image: doubt image]

The above picture shows the fixed position is overridden by absolute

Comment: z-index:1 to the position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

When you set `position:fixed` on your header, this means it has come out of the normal flow of execution.

With this some of your page's content is available but behind the header itself. so a margin-top equal to the header height on the element after header will fix it.

You can also use a `z-index:10` ( a value more that the `position:absolute` div) to make it come on top of the page.

Coming to your second part of the question that `fixed` is changed to `absolute`. I don't see that happening here.